# List of Tannaim and Amoraim with overall summary of their approach to Torah

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, tannaim, amoroim

Has anyone put together a list of Tannaim and Amoraim with analysis from their opinions in each place that they are cited to try to build an overall picture of what their approach to Torah is/what their guiding principles are?  I would find it useful when learning Mishna/Gemara to look them up and see what they are saying in the context of their overall approach.

eg. The kind of analysis that is in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48478/why-do-beit-shammai-and-beit-hillel-always-argue) [and this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108637/what-were-the-main-principles-of-hillel-and-shammais-schools-approach), but not just for Hillel and Shammai, and probably summarised more briefly

Comment: I would also like to see this. I will note that the Koren Noe edition Talmud has side bars for many of the personalities that come up in the Gemara. Many (all?) of them are also found on [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.2a.1?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi), when you see that a Tanna or Amora's name is a link, click it for a short bio

Comment: @RabbiKaii it gives a bio, but I was thinking more along the lines of a brief summary of their hashkafa to put their opinion into context

Comment: Some people have, but it's a controversial approach.

Comment: @N.T. why?  Any sources?

Comment: People feel it diminishes the true complexity and genius of the Ammoraim to simplify everything to a few basic ideas.

Comment: @N.T. I suppose some people might look at it that way, but I think that most people appreciate that you can't distil any person's  life down to a few paragraphs as an accurate representation of them/their opinions, especially great people like the Tannaim and Amoraim. I'm just looking for a bigger picture as context